# Query 2 columns for date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I have a SQL to pull list of issues raised within specified date range. What I am trying to add to this query is to pull all issues where creation date or closed dated is in specified date range.

I just cannot seem to work out how to use `AND`/`OR` to do this

```
SELECT ccm.ISSUEID,
       int.creation_date,
       stat.status_name,
       closed_date
FROM INTRANET.ISSUES int
WHERE to_char(int.creation_date,'YYYYMMDD') between '&startDateYYYYMMDD' AND '&endDateYYYYMMDD'
order by  ccm.ISSUEID
```

Comment: Is this about MS SQL server or MySQL? You listed both in your tags.

Comment: You have columns from at least 3 tables in the select list, but only 1 table in the from list...

Comment: I have stripped down code, it's very long sql with decoding etc. thought I just leave what I thought was necessary. I don't know if it's mysql or ms sql server tbh, I have very basic knowledge of sql, and just querying intranet to get data for reports.